# sending data to a php script

Tags: php, ajax

Whats the best way to send data to the server and have it run through a php script. Bearing in mind I do not want to have the user redirected to a different page and no response needs to be sent back from the server.

...ammended...
I have the following markup.

```
<div id='0001' class='threadWrapper'>
<div class='littleme'>
```

I'm hoping to have a click event associated for the .littleme that submits as its variable the ID for its parent (in this case 0001.
Something like this???

```
 $('.littleme').click(function{
    $.post("path/to/your/script.php", { "threadID":"//value for ID???"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Download [jQuery](http://jquery.com)
Insert it into your script.

You can also just insert it via Google Hosted jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Insert the following javascript:

```
$.post("path/to/your/script.php", { "key":"value", "key2":"value2"});
```

Now your PHP file just looks in the `$_POST` super global to get the data. It is just as if a user requested the page.

Comment: cool, I am actually using jquery already but never find the right function I'm looking for. See my ammened post above.